# Tomcat 7.0 don't started after shutdown.sh

Tags: jakarta-ee, server, tomcat7

Faced such a problem. Tomkat 7.0 was deployed on the server, it worked fine. I made changes to the server.hmml file and decided to restart Tomcat.
Since I only have access to the server via putty, I have entered the commands {tomcat patch} / bin / shoudovn.sh and and {tomat patch} / bin / startup.sh. Passed without errors.
But now I can not open the server in the browser. Trying to turn it off again gives an error

```
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost: 8005. Tomcat may not be running.
Jun 13, 2018 5:46:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base / java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Native Method)
        at java.base / java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (AbstractPlainSoc ketImpl.java:400)
        at java.base / java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (AbstractP lainSocketImpl.java:243)
        at java.base / java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (AbstractPlainSocke tImpl.java:225)
        at java.base / java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:402)
        at java.base / java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:591)
        at java.base / java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:540)
        at java.base / java.net.Socket. <init> (Socket.java:436)
        at java.base / java.net.Socket. <init> (Socket.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer (Catalina.java:505)
        at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Nativ e Method)
        at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Native MethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base / jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (De legatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base / java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer (Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main (Bootstrap.java:430)
```

And if you do startup.sh everything goes well

```
admin@test-ubuntu:~$ /home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/bin/shutdown.sh^C
admin@test-ubuntu:~$ /home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/admin/apache-tomcat-7.0.88/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Sorry for the bad english and maybe the stupid question. I've never encountered servers before.
Where and in what can be my mistake?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm a fool)
Solved a problem. The error was in the file server.xml

Comment: Glad you figured it out!